# Semantic Image Segmentation using Scipy

Tags: opencv, scipy, image-segmentation

Many days ago I saw a user using scipy function to get region of interest (RoI) in an image just by using different colors. I believe it was some sort of filter. Now I'm trying to do the same but I'm not able to find that content anymore.

I would grateful if you could help me with that problem.

Example of Semantic Segmentation:

[image: Example of Semantic Segmentation]

Comment: By ROI, do you mean the rectangular area that fits the certain color code in your image?

Comment: @SriRaghuMalireddi No I mean I need that color from image.